# How can I select a provisioning profile in the VS Code Titanium extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, titanium

I am using the Titanium extension in VS Code, and I would like to know how I can select the provisioning profile when I want to build my project to my connected device.

I click on titanium icon on left panel, in build->ios->device->mydevice I click on the icon like "play" to build, a popup appears to ask to me to select provisioning profile, but I don't know how to do that. I don't have a selector to do it or something else to indicate the asked file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have profiles installed on your system that match the bundle id it will show them in the drop down.

You could also run `ti build -p ios --target dist-appstore` in the app folder and see if it will show you the profiles in the CLI menu

Comment: Thanks for your help, after restarted VS Code the certificate and provisioning profile appears like you said in a drop down.

Comment: @BriceCanti also there's a refresh environment button in the plugin, this also loads it in (takes a few seconds to load). Restart is not required!